# WFS Request against a layer with a foreign table join

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wfs, attribute-joins

I have a Geoserver layer that is pulling from a Postgresql view that contains a left join to a foreign table (data from a SQL Server database).  If I query against the view in PGAdmin (ie. `SELECT * FROM myView WHERE myID = 5`) the correct results are returned.  But if I make a WFS request against the layer (ie. .`..geoserver/READ/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=myViewLayer&CQL_FILTER=myID=5`) the results include ALL records from the joined foreign table, as if the view contained a CROSS JOIN.

The foreign table in question is pulling from a SQL Server instance set up with a tds_fdw foreign data wrapper.  If I actually insert the records from the foreign table into a postgresql table and use this new table in the join instead then my WFS request returns the correct results.

Here are my software versions:
GeoServer:  2.15.2;
Postgresql:  9.6.18;
PostGIS:  2.54;
tds_fdw (foreign data wrapper): 2.0.1

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know the exact SQL you are using. how you created the view (in PG or in GS) and what does the GS log file say when you run the request (with the logging level turned up to GEOTOOLS-DEV level